# Unable to create many to many associations in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm working on a multi-user, multi-room chat app, for which my models are as follows (the App model has been omitted for simplicity):

```
defmodule Elemental.TxChat.User do
  use Elemental.TxChat.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    # The rooms the user is currenly logged into
    many_to_many :rooms, Elemental.TxChat.Room, join_through: "rooms_users"
    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

and

```
defmodule Elemental.TxChat.Room do
  use Elemental.TxChat.Web, :model

  schema "rooms" do
    field :name, :string    
    # The user id that created this room
    field :created_by, :integer
    field :created_from_app, :integer

    many_to_many :members, Elemental.TxChat.User, join_through: "rooms_users"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name, :created_from_app, :created_by])
    |> validate_required([:name, :created_by, :created_from_app])
  end
end
```

Next, I created some rooms and users (three each) from `iex`. Now I got wondering: Suppose I want user1 to belong to room1 and room2, and user2 to belong to room2 and room3 ... how to do it?

It seems to me that while defining the schemas is fine, there has to be an intermediate step that does something like `user1.rooms = [room1, room2]`. So I ended up on [this post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/) and saw an example of `build_assoc`:

```
Ecto.build_assoc(current_user, :post)
```

So this app has users and posts, and is trying to link them. But I don't see how it gets achieved. How does the database/Ecto know which user id to link with which post id?

Anyway, I tried doing this in my app's `iex`:

```
iex(46)> Ecto.build_assoc(user1, :rooms, room1)
%Elemental.TxChat.Room{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "rooms">,
 created_by: 1, created_from_app: 1, id: 2,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-16 05:00:00>,
 members: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :members is not loaded>,
 name: "room1", updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-09-16 05:00:00>}
```

I figured the function call would join `user1` to the model `Room`, using the data in `room1` to find the destination room. My heart sank when I saw `<association :members is not loaded>` in the output, but I thought I should check the database. Guess what, there's no entry in my joining table (rooms_users). :(

I think it's fairly clear that these links between models need to be somehow created, but I seem to have hit a wall. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
Side Note: it would be much easier to make UserRoom model for users_rooms table and create associations with UserRoom.changeset/2
**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I made small example project

```
defmodule Playground.User do
  use Playground.Web, :model
  alias __MODULE__

  schema "users" do
    field :title, :string
    many_to_many :rooms, Playground.Room, join_through: "users_rooms"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title])
    |> validate_required([:title])
  end

  def assoc_changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:title])
    |> validate_required([:title])
    |> add_rooms(params, struct)
  end

  defp add_rooms(changeset, params, %User{rooms: rooms}) do
    case params do
      %{add_rooms: to_be_added} when is_list(to_be_added) ->
        changeset |> put_assoc(:rooms, rooms ++ to_be_added)
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end
end
```

How it works:

```
iex(1)> u = User.changeset(%User{}, %{title: "u"}) |> Repo.insert!
iex(2)> r1 = Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{title: "r1"}) |> Repo.insert!
iex(3)> r2 = Room.changeset(%Room{}, %{title: "r2”}) |> Repo.insert!

iex(4)> u = User.changeset(u, %{title: "u1"}) |> Repo.update!
%Playground.User{
  rooms: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :rooms is not loaded>,
  title: "u1",
  ...
}

iex(5)> u = User.assoc_changeset(u, %{add_rooms: [r1]}) |> Repo.update!
error about #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :rooms is not loaded> here

iex(6)> u = Repo.preload(u, :rooms)
%Playground.User{
  rooms: [],
  title: "u1",
  ...
}

iex(7)> u = User.assoc_changeset(u, %{add_rooms: [r1]}) |> Repo.update!
%Playground.User{
  rooms: [
    %Playground.Room{title: "r1", ...}
  ],
  title: "u1",
  ...
}

iex(7)> u = User.assoc_changeset(u, %{add_rooms: [r2]}) |> Repo.update!
%Playground.User{
  rooms: [
    %Playground.Room{title: "r1", ...},
    %Playground.Room{title: "r2", ...}
  ],
  title: "u1",
  ...
}
```

There is still room for improvements. Helper function add_rooms/3 probably should take user rooms from changeset instead of third argument and be changed to add_rooms/2.
It is up to you to decide what else needs to be improved.

Comment: Side Note: it would be much easier to make UserRoom model for users_rooms table and create associations with UserRoom.changeset/2

Comment: My God . . . that is a lost more complicated than I want. You're right: creating a model is the cleaner (better?) way. Thanks for your inputs and time. :-)

Comment: I'll edit my answer and add 'sidenote' to begining to make it easier for other people with same problem.

Comment: Much better. Right now I'm struggling to get a project done in Phoenix, which is why I have to choose the easier way. But it stands to reason whether a table-only option is really inferior or does it offer advantages under certain conditions. Maybe an exercise for later!